# Suppressing an error in .bash_profile

Tags: bash

I am using the following to display the current branch name in my bash prompt (via `.bash_profile`):

```
GetBranch()
{
  cat ./.git/HEAD | sed 's+^ref: refs/heads/++'
}
```

But when I am in a directory that does *not* correspond to a git repository, I get an error (because `./.git/HEAD does not exist`).

How can I suppress this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect STDERR to /dev/null:

```
GetBranch()
{
    cat ./.git/HEAD 2>/dev/null | sed 's+^ref: refs/heads/++'
}
```

Here's a [quick guide on file descriptors](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#File_Descriptors) that will help explain how `2>/dev/null` works.

---

Alternately, instead of suppressing an error, you could make the command conditional on `./.git/HEAD` existing:

```
GetBranch()
{
    if [[ -e "./.git/HEAD" ]]; then
        cat ./.git/HEAD 2>/dev/null | sed 's+^ref: refs/heads/++'
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Test whether the repository is present first:

```
GetBranch()
{
    if [ -f .git/HEAD ]
    then
        sed 's+^ref: refs/heads/++' < .git/HEAD
    else
        echo "Not a repository" >&2
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `git` itself to return the currently checked-out branch, rather than digging into the repository.

```
GetBranch () {
    git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2> /dev/null
}
```

This will work from any directory in a repository, not just the root.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering the question, but there are a lot of existing scripts to get a git-aware prompt. You may want to use them instead of writing your own. See for example https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh or search "git bash prompt" in you favorite search engine.